# Spark driver, how collect data from all the workers?

Tags: java, apache-spark

wanted to know ,lets all the workers completed their jobs successfully , where the result are getting submitted (may be in master/driver machine ) , what about the memory of driver machine …?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. If you want to get meaningful answers, please be more specific on what you are asking. You can include examples, etc. etc. Otherwise, there is no real answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to know like If data submission (result after successfully execution) of all the workers node is bigger than driver machine memory , in that case how driver is going to manage.

Comment: Again it depends on what you do with the result: do you write it somewhere? What do you do with it? Without knowing what you do with it, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes, You are right , I need to write in HDFS cluster . Please elaborate a bit .

Answer (score 0):

So, according also to your answers in the comments, the answer is: no data is collected on the driver. The data is elaborated and kept only in the executors. The data is moved to the driver only if you perform operations which do so, eg. `collect`.

Comment: Thank a lot, it make sense for me .